# Should unused partitions be removed?

Tags: files, partition, dd, sd-card, disk-image

I downloaded a jessie raspbian image and it shows two partitions.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ fdisk -l 2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img
You must set cylinders.
You can do this from the extra functions menu.

Disk 2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img: 0 MB, 0 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa8790229

                              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img1               1           6       42702+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img2               6         210     1638081   83  Linux
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

I copied the image to a SD which had previously been used (sorry, I don't have the `fdisk` output before copying the image):

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ sudo dd bs=4M if=2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img of=/dev/sdf
411+1 records in
411+1 records out
1725629563 bytes (1.7 GB) copied, 149.961 s, 11.5 MB/s
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Inspecting the device now shows the following:

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdf

Disk /dev/sdf: 31.9 GB, 31914983424 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 30436 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa8790229

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1               5          46       42702+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdf2              47        1646     1638081   83  Linux
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.

[Michael@devserver ~]$ lsblk -f /dev/sdf
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID MOUNTPOINT
sdf
├─sdf1
├─sdf2
├─sdf5
├─sdf6
└─sdf7
[Michael@devserver ~]$ cat /proc/partitions | grep sdf
   8       80   31166976 sdf
   8       81    1243951 sdf1
   8       82          1 sdf2
   8       85      32767 sdf5
   8       86      67584 sdf6
   8       87   29815296 sdf7
[Michael@devserver ~]$ sudo blkid /dev/sdf*
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="boot" UUID="109A-9113" TYPE="vfat"
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Why do partitions `sdf5`, `sdf6`, and `sdf7` still exist?  Should they be removed, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

After copying the image, did you run `partprobe /dev/sdf` or eject & re-insert the card? If you didn't, the kernel might be still using the old partition table for the card.

When you overwrite an entire disk/SD card, you'll need to tell the kernel that it should re-read the partition table. `partprobe` is the easiest command for doing it.

Comment: No, I did not run `partprobe /dev/sdf`, but I did eject & re-insert the card.  Looking at `man partprobe`, it appears that it is just informing the operating system of any partition changes, but doesn't actually change the device, true?  As such, I would expect re-mounting the device will do the same thing, true?

Comment: Ejecting and re-inserting the card might refresh the partition table only if the reader can detect that the card has been removed. Not all card readers can do that. In your fdisk output, the image file has no extended partition, so partition numbers sdf5 and above should not be possible. On the other hand, the presence of a small VFAT partition at the beginning suggests the image might have some sort of MBR/GPT hybrid partitioning, and your `fdisk` might only show the MBR side of the story, while `/proc/partitions` could be showing GPT.